# How to ignore case when using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have problem related to case insensitive search for regular expression. Here is part of the code that I wrote:

```
engType = 'XM665'
```

The value of `engType` was extracted from other files. Based on the engType, I want to find lines in another text file which contain this part and extract description infomation from that line, the description part will be between the `engType` string and `'Serial'`.

for instance:

```
lines = ['xxxxxxxxxxx','mmmmmmmmmmm','jjjjj','xM665 Module 01 Serial (10-11)']
pat = re.compile(engType+'(.*?)[Ss][Ee][Rr][Ii][Aa][Ll]')
for line in lines:
    des = pat.search(line).strip()
    if des:
        break;
print des.group(1).strip()
```

I know the result will be an error, since the case of my string `engType` is different from what it is in `'xM665 Module 01 Serial (10-11)'`, I understand that I can use `[Ss]` to do the case insensitive comparisons as What I have done in the last part of `pat`. However, since my engType is a variable, I could not apply that on a variable. I knew I could search in lower case like:

```
lines = ['xxxxxxxxxxx','mmmmmmmmmmm','jjjjj','xM665 Module 01 Serial (10-11)']
pat = re.compile(engType.lower()+'(.*?)serial')
for line in lines:
    des = pat.search(line.lower()).strip()
    if des:
        break; 
print des.group(1).strip()
```

result:

```
module 01
```

The case is now different compared to `Module 01`. If I want to keep the case, how can i do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.IGNORECASE` is the flag you're looking for.

```
pat = re.compile(engType+'(.*?)[Ss][Ee][Rr][Ii][Aa][Ll]',re.IGNORECASE)
```

Or, more simply `re.compile(engType+'(.*?)serial',re.IGNORECASE)`.

also, bug in this line:

```
des = pat.search(line.lower()).strip()
```

Remove the `.strip()`; if `pat.search()` is `None` you will get an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out re.IGNORECASE in http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

I believe it'll look like:

```
pat = re.compile(engType.lower()+'(.*?)serial', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Ya, This works, thank you! I think re.compile(engType+'(.*?)serial', re.INGORECASE) will do, no need to lower the case of engType